# How to make the save data appear when loading view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

The following code is saving data and loading, but it doesn't show the data when loading view controller.It just says label (Xcode default uilabel).
I believe that I have to use synchronize ,but I am not too sure. May someone help me out.

Implementation file:

```
- (IBAction)minus
{
    mini = mini - 1;
    minus.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", mini];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:mini forKey:@"M"];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    mini = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"M"];
}
```

Header file:

```
IBOutlet UILabel *minus;
```

Comment: So what if you put `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];` after setting the value?

Comment: What are you getting after printing mini in view did load

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; This doesn't work for me, I tried it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:mini forKey:@"M"];
```

Into:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setInteger:mini forKey:@"M"];
[prefs synchronize];
```

And it should work.

And i dont see you setting minus.text in viewdidload.

Comment: `mini` is an integer. This will crash.

Answer (score 0):

As H2CO3 says, you need to end the save process with

[prefs synchronize];

Why don't you open the iPhone Simulator folder to see if a plist file has been created inside Library > Preferences?